# On the implementation of multiple simultaneous tasks of a compiler

Tags: c++, multithreading, multiprocessing, compiler-construction

In my struggle to part ways with interpreters, and while attempting to advance my knowledge in c++, I recently puchased a copy of "C++ In a Nutshell: A Desktop Quick Reference (In a Nutshell (O'Reilly))" and "Writing Compilers and Interpreters (Wiley)". While my college course on C++ taught me how to sort stacks and lists, it taught me nothing on those subjects. I decided I will write a compiler taylored to my unique habits and coding style.

In the case of the recent advent of real multiprocessing capacity, what is worth the required effort? I am fully aware of a multitude of libraries capable of providing threading, and of providing multiprocessing. Defaulting to a resort of pre-existing code does not actualize an efficient learning process due to the fact that that old intimate connection with personally written code would be quite lacking.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand. Are you thinking of implementing your *compiler* in a multithreaded manner, or are you thinking of providing multithreading features for the language you're designing?

Comment: My primary intention is to provide multithreading features in the language I will be designing, but my question is rather regarding the implementation of a multithreaded compiler.

Comment: Parallelism as a useful language feature is the subject of decades of academic research, so that's beyond the scope of a SO question. Probably you should focus on creating a language tailored to your habits, before moving on to habits you intend to develop later :v) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unlikely that you're going to build something that's substantially useful to you in real coding, especially as a first learning experience -- or, in other words, the value is in the journey, not in what you reach at the end.  This is a learning experience.

Thus, I would suggest that you take a couple of things that are of interest to you and that annoy you about existing languages and compilers, and try to improve on them (or at least try out something different).  Beyond that, though, you want to write something that's as simple as possible, so that you can actually complete it.

If you are doing enough multithreaded programming that that's a critical part of what you're thinking about, then it may be worth trying to write something that does multiprocessing.  Otherwise, I would strongly recommend that you leave it out of your first compiler project; it's a big hairy nest of complication, and a compiler is a big enough and hairy enough project without it.

And, if you decide that multithreading is important, you can always add it later.  Better to have something that works first, though, so that you have the fun of using it to keep you from getting bogged down while you add more to it.

Oh, and you definitely don't want to make your first compiler multithreaded internally!  Start with simple, then add complexity once you've done it once and know how much effort is involved.

Answer (score 1):

Compilers are generally implemented as a *pipeline*, where source code goes in one end and a number of processing steps are applied in sequence, and an object file comes out the other end. This kind of processing does not generally lend itself well to multithreading.

With the speed of today's computers, it is rare that a compiler needs to do so much processing that it would benefit from a multithreaded implementation. Within a pipeline, there's only a few things you could usefully do anyway, such as running per-function optimisations in parallel.

A much easier gain can be seen by simply running the compiler in parallel against more than one source file. This can be doing without any multithreading support in the compiler; just write a single-threaded compiler (much less prone to error), and let your build system take care of the parallelism.

Comment: This is mostly true for a C++ compiler. When we talk about a Python compiler for example, then there *is* value in multithreading because the compiler search and compiles dependencies.

Comment: Greg's pipeline is conceptually "big pieces" (parsing of files, building of ASTs, building compilation-unit level symbol tables, function analysis, global analysis, function code generation, optimization).  At that level of granularity, it is pretty hard to get any parallelism (except compiling multiple compilation units in parallel as Greg observed).  If you want to do better, you have to decrease the size of the computation grains.  You can lex and parse in parallel; you can build symbol tables of functions, etc.  Organizing this is hard.

Answer (score 1):

Writing a compiler is hard; languages are complex, people want good code, and they don't want to wait long get it.  This should be obvious from your own experience with using C++ compilers.   Writing a C++ compiler is especially hard, because the language is especially complex (the new C++11 standard making it considerably more complex), and people expect really good code from C++ compilers.

All this complexity, and your lack of background in compilers, suggests that you are not likely to write a C++ compiler, let alone a parallel one.  The GCC and CLANG communities have hundreds of peoples and decades of elapsed development time.   It may be worth your effort to build a toy compiler, to understand the issues better.

Regarding parallelism in the compiler itself, one can take several approaches.

The first is to use a standard library, as you have suggested, and attempt to retrofit an existing compiler with parallelism.    It is odd that few seem to have attempted this task given that GCC and CLANG are open source tools.    But it is also very difficult to parallelize a program that was designed without parallelism in mind.  Where does one find units of parallelism (processing individual methods?), how do you insert the parallelism, how do you ensure that the now-retrofitted compiler doesn't have synchronization problems (if the compiler processes all methods in parallel, where's the guarantee that a signature from one method is actually ready and available to other methods being compiled?) Finally, how does one guarantee that the parallel work dominates the additional thread initialization/teardown/synchronization overhead so that the compiler is actually faster given multiple CPUs?  In addition, thread libraries are a bit difficult to use, and it is relatively easy to make  dumb mistake coding a threading call.  If you have lots of these in your compiler, you have a high probability of such a dumb mistake.  Debugging will be hard.

The second is build a new compiler from scratch, using such libraries.  This requires a lot of work just to get the basic compiler in place, but has the advantage that the individual elements of the compiler can be considered during design, and parallel interlocks designed in   I don't know of any compilers built this way (surely there are some research compilers like this) but its a lot of work, and clearly more work than just writing a non-parallel compiler.  You still suffer from the clumsiness of thread libraries, too.

The third is to find a parallel programming language, and write the compiler in that.  This makes is easier to write parallel code without error, and can allow you to implement kinds of parallelism that might not be possible with a thread library (e.g., dynamic teams of computation, partial orders, ...).  It also has the advantage that the parallel-language compiler can see the parallelism in the code, and can thus generate lower-overhead thread operations.  Because compilers do many computations of varying duration, you don't want a synchronized-data-parallel language; you want one with task parallelism.
Our [PARLANSE](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/products/Parlanse/index.html) compiler is such a programming language, designed with goal of doing parallel symbolic (eg non-numeric) computations appropriate for compilers.  Now you need a a parallel compiler and the energy to build a new compiler from scratch.

The fourth approach is to use a parallel language and a predefined library of compiler-typical activities (parsing, symbol table lookup, flow analysis, code generation) and build your compiler that way.  At then you don't have to reinvent the basic facilities of the compiler and can get on with building the compiler itself.

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) is exactly such a set of tools and libraries designed to allow one to build complex code generation/transformation or analysis tools.  DMS has an [full C++11 front end](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CppFrontEnd.html) available that uses all the DMS (parallel) support machinery.

We've used DMS to carry out massive C++ analysis and transformation tasks.  The parallelism is there, and it works; we could do more if we tried.  We have not attempted to build a real parallel compiler; we don't see the market for it considering that other C++ compilers are free and well established.   I expect someday that somebody will find a niche place where a parallel C++ compiler is needed, and then this machinery like this is likely to be a foundation; its too much work to start from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of language you wish to compile.

If you think of creating a language today, it should be based on modules, rather than the header/source way C++ is built. With such languages, the compiler is often given a single "target" (a module) and automatically compiles the dependencies (other modules), this is for example what the Python compiler does.

In this case, multithreading yields an immediate gain: you can simply parallelize the multiple modules compilations. This is relatively easy, just think about leaving a "mark" that you are compiling a given module to avoid doing it several times in parallel.

Going further is not immediately useful. While optimizations could probably be applied in parallel for example, it would require paying attention to the synchronization of the models they are applied to. The nice thing about compiling multiple modules in parallel is that they are mostly independent during compilation and read-only once ready, which alleviates most synchronization issues.